# Understanding map in cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, modules, homology-cohomology

To find $[f] \in \pi_{2n-1}(\mathbb{S}^n)$ such that $H(f) = \pm 2$, where $H(f)$ is the Hopf invariant, we define the following map $h : \mathbb{S}^n \vee \mathbb{S}^n \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^n$ defned by $h(\star,x) = h(x,\star) = x$ where $\star$ is the basepoint of $\mathbb{S}^n$.

Since $H^n(\mathbb{S}^n) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and $H^{n}(\mathbb{S}^n \vee \mathbb{S}^n) \simeq \mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}$, fixed $y$ a generator of $H^{n}(\mathbb{S}^n)$ I'd like to know why $$h^{*}(y) = (y,y) = (0,y)+(y,0)$$ since I'm unable to compute it directly based on the definition of $h$.

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: consider the composition of $h$ with the inclusion maps $i_1, i_2: S^n \to S^n \vee S^n$.

Comment: @JHF I don't understand how to compute it with the definition, should I pass from cochains? Could you pleas show me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fold map $h: S^n \vee S^n \to S^n$, the induced map in $H^n$ is a group homomorphism $h^*: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, where we identify each $H^n(S^n)$ with a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.  Write $h^*(1) = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ for integers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$.  To deduce what these integers are, consider the map induced by the composite $h \circ i_1, h \circ i_2: S^n \to S^n$, where $i_1, i_2: S^n \to S^n \vee S^n$ are inclusions into each of the wedge summands.  By functoriality, $(h \circ i_1)^*(1) = i_1^* h^*(1) = i_1^*(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = \lambda_1$.  On the other hand, $h \circ i_1$ is the identity, so the induced map takes generators to generators, so $\lambda_1 = \pm 1$.  Similarly, $\lambda_2 = \pm 1$.  So $h^*(1) = (\pm 1, \pm 1)$.  By picking generators consistently (or by composing with a suitable isomorphism), you can arrange for $h^*(1) = (1, 1)$.